# Binary operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'CGPoint' and 'Int' Using Guard

Tags: ios, swift

In my game I have a ball that can be swiped. I'm trying to make it so that if the user cannot drag the ball above a certain point. However, if they swipe and accidently go into that point, then the ball will still move. Whenever I put `guard location < 100 else {return}`, the error:

> "Binary operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'CGPoint' and 'Int'"

shows up and I do not know how to fix it. By the way, will the `guard` make so the ball will still have its velocity when the user accidentally goes above the line?

Here is my code:

```
for touch in touches {
    let location = touch.location(in: self)
    let node = self.atPoint(location)

    guard location < 100 else { return }
    if ball.frame.contains(location)  {
        touchPoint = location
        touching = true
    }
}
```

Comment: cast in to CGFloat or try using 100.0

Comment: I have tried that but when I cast in to CGFloat it says gives the same error, and when I use 100.0 it says I'm using a double

Comment: Casting makes no sense. You can't cast a CGPoint to a simple scalar like a `Double` or a `CGFloat`. See my answer.

Comment: oops i misread cgpoint as cgfloat, my bad

Answer (score 2):

The error is telling you what is wrong. A `CGPoint` is a struct with an `x` and a `y` value. It doesn't make sense to compare a point to a single integer value.

You need to compare the points x or y position to some value, not the whole point.

```
    guard location < 100 else { return }
```

might read

```
    guard location.y < 100 else { return }
```

instead.

Comment: Duncan, I got the program to run, but the guard isn't even working. Is my code set up right to do what I said I want above?

Comment: Edit your question to show your updated code at the end of your post. Also show the whole function that contains your guard statement. And you need to tell us what you want to happen. Do you want to exit the function if the location's x or y position is greater than or equal to 100?

Comment: @LeoDabus, you **can** return inside a loop. It bails out of the loop and returns from the function. Try it. It works.

Comment: Well, you can do that too, but the effect is not what you'd expect. In the case of forEach, the return returns out of the closure, so it's effect is the same as continue in a for...in loop.